# How to input arguments after compiling python program with PyInstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

After `import sys`, I use `sys.argv` to get input arguments.

But after I compile my program with PyInstaller, the exe program will not accept my input. Instead, it uses the default value I set for the program.

If I run it with  `python this_script.py` it waits for my input to specify the `wait_time`. However, after I compile it with PyInstaller, if I double click the exe file there is no place for me to input the `wait_time`.

How can I compile it and let the exe file accept my input?

```py
import sched, time
import sys
    
s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
    
# wait_time is an integer representing how many seconds to wait.
def do_something(sc, wait_time): 
    # Here will be the code for doing something every after "wait_time " seconds
    sc.enter(wait_time, 1, do_something, (sc, wait_time))  
    
    try:
        wait_time = int(sys.argv[1])
    except IndexError:
        wait_time = 5    
    
    
# s.enter(wait_time, 1, do_something, (s,))
s.enter(wait_time, 5, do_something, (s, wait_time))
s.run()
```

Comment: can you give us a small short concise and working example of your code that demonstrates this problem? Have you attempted to run it as a script and not a compiled executable?

Comment: How are you running the resulting `.exe` file? Are you running it from a command prompt or are you clicking on it?

Comment: Are you supplying any command line arguments?

Comment: Above is the code. I want the program repeatly doing something every 5 mins. Then I can input wait_time = 300. I want to run the .exe directly instead of using python command line.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you click on the exe to open it:

Usually, when you double click the exe, there is only one argument which is `<EXEfilename>`. Create a shortcut for that exe. In the properties for that shortcut, you will see a property called `Target` which will contain `<EXEfilename>` change that to `<EXEfilename> <arg1> <arg2>`. When you use this shortcut to open the exe, it calls the target, which is this call `<EXEfilename> <arg1> <arg2>`. You can then access `arg1` and `arg2` using `sys.argv`

If you use command line:

Just call it as `C:\> <EXEfilename> <arg1> <arg2>`

Comment: Thank you! After I change add <arg1> in the target, it works. But is there any way to allow me input the arg1 interactively?

Comment: I see this problem is due the the windows system. For linux, we can just run <EXEfilename> <arg1> in the shell. For windows, we used to double click the exe, we cannot input <arg1> unless we use cmd or add a gui to the program.

Comment: Or you can use the console with that opens up. If you are using python 2 its `arg1 = raw_input('Enter arg1')` if you are using python 3 its `arg1 = input('Enter arg1')`. This lets users enter the args in interactively.

Answer (score 1):

`sys.arg[0]` is helpful if you run the program through command line. Instead of using `sys.arg[0]`, use

> input()

You can also use `input("<Statement to show to user>: ")`, to show a statement to the user. Then create your executable **(.exe)** by compiling the Python script using

> pyinstaller --onefile pythonscript.py

Simply double click on the generated **.exe** file, a console will appear showing the following statement, *Statement to show to user:* .

You can also take multiple user inputs from user by using multiple `input()` statements in pythonscript.py. For example:

```
input_customer_segment = input("Enter a customer segment (For example: Daily user): ")
input_number_of_months = input("Enter number of months of consumption: ")
```

This will take multiple user inputs on pressing `Enter` after every input in the console that appears.