# How to get python script file path that has been compiled in binary .exe?

Tags: python, python-os

I have python script `myscript.py` that I compiled with pyinstaller with the following command: `pyinstaller -F myscript.py` . Now I get a file called `myscript.exe`  . In my script, there are line that I wrote to get the path of this file using the following code:

```
this_file = os.path.realpath(__file__)
src = this_file
filenameOnly, file_extension = os.path.splitext(src)
exeFile = filenameOnly+'.exe'
print ('exe file to check', exeFile)
if os.path.exists(exeFile):
    src = exeFile
print ('Binary file', src)
```

But this works well only if the `.exe` file is having the same name as the initial `.py` file. If I rename the binary file, my script will not detect that change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with `src = sys.executable`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `sys.argv` to access command line parameters. The first value in `sys.argv` is the name of the program. e.g:

```
...
filenameOnly = sys.argv[0]
exeFile = filenameOnly + '.exe'
...
```

Here are some related stackoverflow links for further reading on this subject.

[sys.argv[1] meaning in script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117530/sys-argv1-meaning-in-script)

[How to input arguments after compiling python program with PyInstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25984395/after-compiling-python-program-how-to-input-arguments)