# How to pass arguments in python exe files?

Tags: python, selenium, argv

I have created .exe for below code. I created /dist and now try to execute .exe but nothing has happened. Please suggest how to proceed or I am doing something wrong? Is it possible to execute below code using .exe. Please suggest.

```
from selenium import webdriver  
from time import sleep  
import sys  

driver = webdriver.Firefox()  # To connect to web browser use webdriver imported from selenium
driver.get('https://web.whatsapp.com/')

name = sys.argv[1]
msg = sys.argv[2]
filepath = sys.argv[3]


def whatsapp(name, msg="", filepath=""):

    input('Enter anything after scanning QR code')

    user = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@title = "{}"]'.format(name))
    user.click()

    if msg != "":
        msg_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='main']/footer/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]")
        msg_box.send_keys(msg)  # To send message

        button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='main']/footer/div[1]/div[3]/button")
        button.click()  # click send button

    if filepath != "":
        attachment_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@title = "Attach"]')
        attachment_box.click()  # click attachment icon button

        image_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
        '//input[@accept="image/*,video/mp4,video/3gpp,video/quicktime"]')
        image_box.send_keys(filepath)  # To send filepath

        sleep(3)  # use to set delay time of 3 sec. It will first find the image box,

        send_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@data-testid="send"]')
        send_button.click()  # click send button


if name != "":
    whatsapp(name, msg, filepath)  # parameters are passed at run time using sys.argv

    if msg != "" and filepath == "":
        print("Only message sent successfully")
    elif msg == "" and filepath != "":
        print("Only attachment sent successfully")
    elif msg == "" and filepath == "":
        print("Both message and attachment not sent")
    else:
        print("Both message and attachment sent successfully")
else:
    print("name or group name cannot be empty")
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of [after compiling python program, how to input arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25984395/after-compiling-python-program-how-to-input-arguments)

Answer of ashwinjv from the above link

**If you click on the exe to open it:
Usually, when you double click the exe, there is only one argument which is `<EXEfilename>`. Create a shortcut for that exe. In the properties for that shortcut, you will see a property called Target which will contain `<EXEfilename>` change that to `<EXEfilename> <arg1> <arg2>`. When you use this shortcut to open the exe, it calls the target, which is this call `<EXEfilename> <arg1> <arg2>`. You can then access arg1 and arg2 using sys.argv
If you use command line:
Just call it as `C:\> <EXEfilename> <arg1> <arg2>`**