# Passing arguments to python exe

Tags: python

I am trying to create a python executable using below code.

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc as po
import os
#variables
server = 'DESKTOP-9B94UPJ' 
database = 'DB1' 
username = 'etluser' 
password = 'password' 
rawfile_directory='E:\\Projects\\Ebay\\ETLApp\\'
cnxn = po.connect('DRIVER={SQL 
Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)

df=pd.read_csv(rawfile_directory+"SPSS_Files\\"+filename,usecols=var_filteredCols)

cnxn = po.connect('DRIVER={SQL 
Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
     sql_stmt = "INSERT INTO "+var_table+" ("+var_DBCols+") values("+var_placeholder+")"
     cursor = cnxn.cursor()
     cursor.fast_executemany = True
     cursor.executemany(sql_stmt, df.values.tolist())
           # print(f'{len(df)} rows inserted to the {MY_TABLE} table')
     cursor.commit()
     cursor.close()
     cnxn.close()
```

I have created an exe using pyinstaller

```
pyinstaller --onefile etl.py
```

I want to pass the database credential and the folder path on the runtime to the exe. Can any of experts advise me how to achieve this? Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use `argparse`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create a GUI program that uses a user interface to extract credentials, you are probably left with command-line manipulation.  You can easily do the above by passing the arguments in and then extracting them using  [`sys.argv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv)

For example:

```
import sys
if len(sys.argv) < 6:
    raise ValueError("Not enough commandline arguments! Please run with <executable> <server> <database> <username> <password> <folder_path>")

server = sys.argv[1]
database = sys.argv[2]
username = sys.argv[3]
password = sys.argv[4]
rawfile_directory= sys.argv[5]
```

Then you can run your executable from command prompt using something like

```
C:\> <EXEfilename> DESKTOP-9B Ebay_CX etluser password E:\Projects\Ebay\ETLApp
```

If you want a fancier, more polished commandline interface, consider using [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) so you can give your end users more help on how to use the different arguments to your executable, e.g. with usage instructions, --options instead of args, --help support, etc.

You could also ask for user input during runtime, e.g. after running the executable with `input()` but this is less standard

See also: [after compiling python program, how to input arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25984395/after-compiling-python-program-how-to-input-arguments)